# strftime("%A") output is string. but assigning variable is expecting Int

Tags: python

I am converting the date to Day of the month.
when I am executing Ia m getting the following error.

```
  File ".\date.py", line 8, in <module>
    ans=datetime.date(year,month,date)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

I don't understand this error. Return type is Str as expected.
I have not declared as int.
I am using Python3 and not getting why it is complaining about the datetype.

Comment: `%A` returns the day of week like `Thursday`. How can you use that as an integer?

Comment: yes that is my question...not getting why it is complaining that it is expecting a integer.

Comment: TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
 is the error I am getting

Comment: The arguments to `datetime.date()` are supposed to be numbers, not strings. What's confusing about that?

Comment: can you share the parameters you are passing to the function?

Comment: Could you please expand on the question with an example including the inputs you've tried?

Comment: Make a  reproducible example. Refer to  [mcve] as a guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two issues.

First, to get the day of the month, you should use `%d`, not `%A` with `strftime()`.

```
date = time.strftime("%d");
```

Second, this returns the day as a string, not as an integer, but `datetime.date()` requires its arguments to be integers, so you need to convert it with `int(date)`

```
date = int(time.strftime("%d"))
```

But there's really no need to use `strftime()` in the first place. If you have a `date` object, you can simply access its `day` property to get the day of the month.